# Setting Html Attributes in Tag Helpers in ASP.NET Core 2.0 Views

Tags: c#, asp.net-core-2.0, asp.net-core-tag-helpers

I am migrating my web application from ASP.NET MVC to ASP.NET Core 2.0. But I having problem on setting html attributes in the Tag Helpers for Select Tag. For example, in my old project I have the below html helper for drop-down list.

```
var cssClass = "select-arrow " + Model.ControlCss;                        
@Html.DropDownListFor(model => model.Value, options, "", new { @class = cssClass })
```

Here, I have used the bellow html attributes for the html helper class to add another CSS classes.

> **new { @class = cssClass }**

Now my question is how do I set the html attributes in asp.net core? Does the blow code work? Please let me know the details.

```
<select asp-for="Value" asp-items="options" class="form-control, cssClass"></select>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can insert a string using `@PropertyName`:

```
<select asp-for="Value" asp-items="options" class="form-control select-arrow @Model.ControlCss" />
```

Comment: Thanks for your answer. Can you please suggest me the alternative for @Html.ValidationMessage("InputText") in Tag Helper.

Comment: I'm sure folks will here will be able to help but please post additional questions separately.